# Use conditional formatting to filter data or copy it elsewhere

Tags: excel, filter, formula, highlight, conditional-formatting

I know how to add rules for Conditional Formatting.  My current rule searches for a bunch of terms in an array and highlights whatever rows contains it.

But it only highlights data.   I would like to take all highlighted rows and send them to another sheet, or at least, filter by data selected.  I have tried searching for formulas that check for a cell backcolor but there doesn't seem to be any way outside of using VBA, which I want to avoid.

Is there anyway to filter or manipulated the highlighted data without VBA?

Here's a very simple [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l85F6.png).  Basicially I would like to be able to filter or copy all the rows which are highlighted.

Comment: Have you tried filtering by color?

Comment: lol I didn't even know you could do that.  Thank you.